# Set configuration to "Release" when publishing

Tags: .net-core, release, publish

I have a project that I'm publishing using the dotnet CLI's `dotnet publish` command.

Since I only ever publish with a release intent, I'd like to make it so that when I issue a `dotnet publish` the build and publishing happen with the "Release" configuration but still use the "Debug" inside Visual Studio when I'm debugging/testing.

I know I can manually change the configuration from Visual Studio's configuration/properties window and can specify the `-c Release` argument but is there some tag I can include in my `.csproj` file that says "when publishing use 'Release' by default"?

Comment: publishing and debugging in VS are two completely different things. When you debug in VS, it doesn't run a publish first. It just compiles it and runs the DLL. How are you publishing now? Command line like this: `dotnet publish -c Release` ?

Comment: @Andy, please actually read the question, first, before commenting. I have no idea why you would go on about "debugging doesn't run a publish first" out of the blue, when nothing of the sort is even suggested in my question.

Comment: If you know you can use -c Release, what's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an opened issue regarding this [here](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/10357).

You may check it, specially this @nguerrera [comment](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/10357#issuecomment-506984068).

Answer (score 2):

Create batch/powershell file for the command

```
dotnet publish -c Release
```

save it into `release.cmd` and run that when needed

Comment: I had to write `-c=Release` instead of `-c Release`, but the command-line switch works as expected.